# For loop with increasing variable

Tags: python

I am writing a for loop to quickly obtain user data for a set. To keep the data useful, each has to have it's own variable it saves to. So far, I have:

```
hey = ['11', '12', '13', '14']
x = 0
for i in hey:
    x += 1
    showtimesx = raw_input('NOG >')
    print showtimesx

print ""   
print "Showtime at 11: " + showtimesx
print "Showtime at 12: " + showtimesx
print "Showtime at 13: " + showtimesx
print "Showtime at 14: " + showtimesx
```

The last prints are just to check that the showtimesx have increased in value. However, every time I run it, all of them just end up equaling the last inputted value.

I have attempted to move the x += 1 line, have the x = 0 line inside the loop and a series of other things, but none of them work.

How can I fix that?

Comment: What do you think would cause the value of `showtimesx` to change between those lines of code?

Comment: When you write a program, things happen in order. All the changes to `showtimesx` in your code occur before any of the attempts to display it, and it stores a single value. The results should not be surprising. Hint: `hey` stores multiple values. Perhaps you could use a similar technique to store multiple values in `showtimesx`.

Comment: You probably want a [Dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use lists:

```
hey = ['11', '12', '13', '14']
showtimes = [raw_input('NOG >') for i in hey]

print ""   
print "Showtime at 11: " + showtimes[0]
print "Showtime at 12: " + showtimes[1]
print "Showtime at 13: " + showtimes[2]
print "Showtime at 14: " + showtimes[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that for each loop that your `for` does, `showtimesx` gets overwritten.
This code blow will help:

```
hey = ['11', '12', '13', '14']
x = 0
showtimesx = []
for n in hey :
    for i in n:
        x += 1
        showtimesx.append(input('NOG >')) #Adds the user's input too end of showtimesx                                              
        print (showtimesx)                #FYI: input() is equal to raw_input() in python3
        break

print ("")
print ("Showtime at 11: " + showtimesx[0])
print ("Showtime at 12: " + showtimesx[1])
print ("Showtime at 13: " + showtimesx[2])
print ("Showtime at 14: " + showtimesx[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

## List Approach

If you have to iterate through a and perform an operation with each value, try [`enumerate()`, which will return both the value from your list and its position in the list](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html).
This will also allow you to change the values in your list by index.

```
mylist = ['11', '12', '13', '14']

for index, value in enumerate(mylist):
    if int(value) == 12:
        mylist[index] = "fifteen instead"

print mylist  # ['11', 'fifteen instead', '13', '14']
```

## Dictionary Approach

In your case, [consider using a dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm). This will allow you to more easily save them and query them back later by name ("key") instead of remembering some index like `mylist[1]` or having to search through it until you find a value.

```
>>> colors = {"pineapples": "sorry, no pineapples"}  # initial key: value pairs
>>> colors["red"] = "#FF0000"  # add value
>>> print colors["red"]  # retrieve a value by key
#FF0000
```

Here's an example as a complete function of your case:

```
def showtimes(list_of_times, display=True):

    dict_of_times = {}  # empty dictionary to store your value pairs

    print "please enter values for the {} showtimes".format(len(list_of_times))
    for value in list_of_times:
        dict_of_times[value] = raw_input("NOG > ")

    if display:  # Let the user decide to display or not
        print ""
        for time in sorted(dict_of_times.keys()):  # dictionaries are unsorted
            print "Showtimes at {}: {}".format(time, dict_of_times[time])

    return dict_of_times  # keep your new dictionary for later


hey = ['11', '12', '13', '14']
showtimes(hey)  # pass a list to your function
```